# Eliminar elementos repetidos de un Arreglo

Tags: javascript, array, funciones, bucle-for, variables

Tengo un método `buscaElimina` con dos parámetros , arreglo y número.
Necesito eliminar del arreglo los elementos que coinciden con el número pasado como parámetro.

Por ejemplo:

```
buscaElimina([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)  > [1,3,4]
```

Lo probé así:

```
function buscaElimina(arreglo,num){
  for (var i = 0; i <arreglo.length, i++ )
      if (arreglo[i]!== num ); { 
        return arreglo
      };
}
```

pero me devuelve el arreglo sin modificar

Comment: Utiliza un array auxiliar en el que cuando pase el filtro del if, añades ese elemento al array auxiliar

Comment: Una cosa es eliminar los elementos repetidos y otra eliminar todos los elementos de un numero especifico. Te recomiendo [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/412875/edit) tu pregunta para evitar estos malentendidos

Comment: tu función te devolvía el arreglo igual, porque simplemente estabas comparando si un elemento del arreglo con el número a eliminar era diferente, cuando esto sucedía simplemente terminabas el programa retornando el mismo arreglo sin modificar.

Answer (score 0):

El objeto `Array` ya tiene un método `filter` que te devuelve un array con los elementos que cumplen una condición.

Simplemente tendrías que obtener los elementos que no coinciden con el número buscado:

```
let filteredArray = array.filter(x => x !== num);
```

Comment: Hola Asier, muchas gracias.- No conocia ese metodo. Saludos

Comment: Hola @Rene si la respuesta te fue útil, deberías considerar marcarla como "Aceptada" para cerrar esta pregunta

Comment: Hola Andres, si. No se donde marcarla,. Ahora me fijo. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

*tienes que revisar errores de sintaxis, los ;{} son importantes en js, este seria una forma de hacerlo*

```
arreglo = [1, 2, 3, 4];
function buscaElimina(arreglo, num) {
    nuevoArreglo = arreglo.filter(x => x !== num);
    return nuevoArreglo;
}
buscaElimina(arreglo, 2);
```

Comment: Hola Wilber, ahi lo entendi! Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tengo una respuesta sencilla pero poderosa

```js
const values = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const num = 2;

console.log(values.filter(x=>x!=num));
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos :D

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo funciona el código. Lee [answer].